# How to get no data found message if json in empty

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am doing some json parsing using jquery. I want to raise a message if no data in json array. So I used the code bellow and got the condition true but no message appended in html div.

my code:

```
$( "#refresh" ).click(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/get_latest_verification", function(obj){
        if(json.length==0){
             $('<p>no updates found</p>').appendTo('#rr');
        }
    });
});
```

Can Anyone correct me.

Comment: `if(obj.length==0){`...

Comment: tried that also, but nothing worked...

Comment: use trim() and check....

Comment: If get_latest_verification is running on a different server you need to be aware of [**CORS**](http://enable-cors.org/) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). If CORS isn't enabled (which it seems to be the case) that request will never succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is you question? Just check what request finished and json is empty or request is failed ([use promise pattern](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)):

```
var url = "http://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/get_latest_verification";
$( "#refresh" ).click(function() {
     $.getJSON(url).done(function (json) {
          if(!json || json.length === 0){
              $('<p>no updates found</p>').appendTo('#rr');
           }
     }).fail(function () {
         $('<p>no updates found</p>').appendTo('#rr');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a small error :

You should check `if(obj.length==0)`

And not as you did.

why ?

becuase this is the argument of your callback which is declared as :

`function(obj){...}`

**notice :**

I surely hope that you have cors enable on the server because running your code display:

> *XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/get_latest_verification.
>   Origin http://run.jsbin.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

And I dont see any allow -domain header in the reponse :

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Cache-Control:no-cache
Origin:http://run.jsbin.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: @PK10 My Friend , Against this http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq0n7.jpg - there is nothing we can do. ( ask for their jsonp api)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$.isEmptyObject(obj)
```

instead of json.length == 0

This will work for both empty arrays and empty objects

See the documentation page [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/#jQuery-isEmptyObject-object).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too,

```
if($.isEmptyObject(obj)) { //do you work here }
```

Documentation : [**isEmptyObject**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isemptyobject/)